# AngularJS Typescript Error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemSvcProvider <- itemSvc

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, typescript, code-injection

I've done a couple projects in AngularJS but this is the first I've done in Typescript.  I'm using this project as a way to continue learning angular but also as a way to learn Typescript so I'm almost positive this error is occurring due to something I'm not understanding, but I'm having the hardest time figuring out the issue.  Everything I've read about this error is I have a typo somewhere but I've been over it so many times that I finally decided to ask for your folks' help.  Needless to say, I've looked through the numerous similar questions here on Stack Overflow but still couldn't find anything which lead me to the solution.

The error I'm getting:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemSvcProvider <- itemSvc
```

ItemApp.ts:

```
module ItemApp {
    'use strict'

    var appModule = angular.module('ItemApp', ['ngRoute']);
    appModule.config(['$routeProvider',
            function ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                        templateUrl: '/App/Item/Views/ItemList.html',
                        controller: ItemCtrl
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            }
    ]);
    appModule.factory('ItemSvc', ItemApp.ItemSvc);
    appModule.controller('ItemCtrl', ItemApp.ItemCtrl);
}
```

ItemCtrl.ts:

```
module ItemApp {
    'use strict'

     export class ItemCtrl implements IItemCtrl {
        public id: string;
        public item: MainItem;
        public testString: string;
        private itemSvc: any;

        constructor($scope, ItemSvc) {
            this.testString = 'Testing';
            this.itemSvc = ItemSvc;
            this.itemSvc.getItem(this.id).then((data) => this.item = data);
        }
    }

    ItemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'itemSvc'];
}
```

ItemSvc.ts:

```
module ItemApp {
    'use strict'

    export class ItemSvc {
        httpService: ng.IHttpService;
        qService: ng.IQService;

        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, $q: ng.IQService) {
            this.httpService = $http;
            this.qService = $q;
        }

        getItem(id): ng.IPromise<MainItem> {
            var deferred = this.qService.defer();
            this.httpService.get('/api/item/' + id).then(res => {
                deferred.resolve(res.data);
            }).catch(res => {
                deferred.reject(res);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

         static Factory($http: ng.IHttpService, $q: ng.IQService) {
            return new ItemSvc($http, $q);
        }
    }

    ItemSvc.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Items";
}

<div ng-app="ItemApp">
    Item Index
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

App/Item/Views/ItemList.html:

```
<div ng-controller="ItemCtrl as ic" >
     Item HTML<br />
     {{ic.testString}}<br />
</div>
```

The routing is at least working because I'm getting an HTML screen that shows:

```
Item Index
Item HTML
{{ic.testString}}
```

So the controller isn't loading the testString value and I'm getting the error message.  Anything immediately jump out as wrong?  I'd be incredibly appreciative of any help!

Comment: TYPO, `itemSvc` != `ItemSvc` @ `ItemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'itemSvc'];` which should be `ItemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'ItemSvc'];`. It is case sensitive

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  Yep, that was definitely a problem so I fixed the typo and now I get the even lovelier (more) abstract error: "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined"  Am I not seeing another typo I have?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the appModule.config.  If I take out "controller: ItemCtrl" I get the error "Argument 'ItemCtrl' is not a function, got undefined".  So I think it has something to do with that.  I tried implementing the config as a separate class, but then the routing didn't happen at all.  Argh! I feel like I'm so close.  I'm completely experiencing the angular roller coaster of emtions: http://www.bennadel.com/resources/uploads/2013/feelings_about_angularjs_over_time.png

Comment: So I removed the "Controller" from the route provider and got an "ItemCtrl is not a function, got undefined" error.  So looks like it's supposed to be in the route provider but when it is, I get the "Argument 'fn' is not a function..." error.  So I'm kind of in an error catch-22 here!

Comment: Okay, figured it out!  So the typo was one issue (thanks PSL!).  The other issue was I defined the controller in the route provider and then on the ItemList.html, I marked up ng-controller.  Once I removed the ng-controller and added ControllerAs: 'ic' to the route provider, my testString started showing up on the page.  Okay, back on one of those angular roller coaster peaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's Dependency Injection is case sensitive. Use consistent casing between `appModule.factory('ItemSvc', ItemApp.ItemSvc);` and `ItemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'itemSvc'];`

## Fix

Change `appModule.factory('ItemSvc', ItemApp.ItemSvc);` to `appModule.factory('itemSvc', ItemApp.ItemSvc);`